# OP-AMP circuit for voltage to current conversion

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, current-measurement, current-source

[image]

It is required to design a circuit for voltage to current converter to have a current output with 4-20mA. So, I wonder if the above circuit will work. Suppose that the input ranges from 1 to 5V.

Answer (score 2):

No, that circuit does not produce a current output that maintains current amplitude across a decent range of load impedances. Your "output current" is dependent on the load you have connected. Try the "Howland current source" instead: -

[image]

Or maybe this type of constant current sink: -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The mistake you are making is that a 4-20 mA sender (the sensor) does not **supply** 4-20 mA into the loop ....it limits an externally supplied loop to the signal current level desired.
In the other answer, the first option (Howland) is clearly not suitable since it tries to supply current to the loop .....however the second option would work since it limits loop current irrespective of load voltage and impedance (it does have a problem in the required ground continuity, but that is a minimal annoyance in most installations).

You should read up on 4-20 mA current providers such as the TI [XTR115](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/xtr115.pdf) or [XTR117](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/xtr117.pdf) which shows the correct methodology.
[image] 
The majority of industrial setting use 24 V or above for the loop source so whatever you stand up on the loop has to be able to withstand this voltage. Most op amps are unsuitable for this task unless specifically designed for the job with the correct output buffers/drivers.

Comment: I don't see any reason to believe his requirement is for a loop-powered circuit. Many instruments (called "4-wire") have a separate supply because they require more power than a loop can realistically supply.

Comment: You are absolutely right....there are 2, 3 and 4 wire configurations for 4-20 mA industrial loops. However anything other than 2 wire becomes difficult to manage when you have serial (redundant) receivers or senders. It has absolutely nothing to do with the power supplied in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

It won't have the desired functionality because the load resistance for such circuits can vary over a wide range.

Here is a simple circuit that should work for a grounded load, and does not depend on resistor matching to give a high output impedance as the Howland and improved Howland circuits do:

(op-amps must be rail-to-rail I/O types)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fE5vpE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The shown circuit has a compliance of about Vdd - 2.1V so it will work with a load resistance of up to (Vdd-2.1V)/0.02A. You can divide the input voltage down to get your required 1-5V input voltage using a 3K/2K resistor pair.